# Can't override siri menu button between views

Tags: swift, tvos, uitapgesturerecognizer, siri-remote

So I've been able to successfully override the menu button's default behavior using a tapGesture recognizer. I have something like this

```
func addMenuButtonLock() {
    defaultMenuTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector())
    defaultMenuTapRecognizer!.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(integer: UIPressType.Menu.rawValue)]
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(defaultMenuTapRecognizer!)
}

func removeMenuButtonLock() {
    if defaultMenuTapRecognizer != nil {
        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(defaultMenuTapRecognizer!)
        defaultMenuTapRecognizer = nil
    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    addMenuButtonLock()
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    removeMenuButtonLock()
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    addMenuLock()
}

override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    removeMenuLock()
}
```

But it seems like during transitions and segues (as in the animation between one view controller being replaced/covered with another), if the menu button in pressed it seems to fallback to the default of popping the view controller off the stack. I feel like I've tried everything, including:

- Not removing the tapgesturerecognizer at all
- Calling them before calling the super methods for the view appearance functions
- Adding a tapgesturerecognizer to the underlying navigation controller (subclassing it)
- Overriding pressesBegan, pressesCancelled and pressesEnded. In this case, it captures the menu press, but despite me never calling their super method, the view is still popped. I'm seriously lost.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the view controller you're adding this code to is being displayed? Is it being presented modally, pushed into a UINavigationController, etc? Also, can you share what the view controller hierarchy is: what view controllers are involved, which view controllers contain others as children, etc.